# How to solve these types of sum puzzles

Tags: puzzle

I have a math puzzle book, and in the chapter I'm working in right now, there's is this type of question that gets asked in one form or another. An example of such a puzzle:

How many darts are needed to score exactly 100?

[image: doelwit]

How could one go about without checking every combination? Yes, a simple observation shows that one could not throw 1 dart to score 100, neither 2 darts, since the sum of the two highest numbers does not exceed 100. But with 3, 4, or 5 the number of combinations to check gets... well... out of hand.

Another puzzle of this form is:

*Can you find 6 odd numbers that add up to 100?*

But the question to finding answers to these questions remains the same: is there a good way of efficiently finding these numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A)** Check for $3$-darts and $4$-darts solutions.

This method is simple, but works mainly for $3$ or $4$ darts.

Make the set of possible sums of $2$ darts:

$\color{red}{A = \{a_j\}} = \{16+16, 16+17, 16+23, \ldots, 39+40 \}$; 
then sort it and remove repeating values (for more comfortable usage):

$\color{red}{A} = \{32,33,34,\;39,40,41,\;46,47,48,\;55,56,57,\;62,63,64,\;78,79,80 \}$;

Then look for remainders to $100$:

$\color{green}{B = \{100 - a_j\} } = \{68,67,66,\; 61,60,59,\;52,53,54,\; 45,44,43,\;38,37,36,\; 22,21,20\}$.

If there is solution of $3$ darts, then set $\color{green}{B}$ would contain one of given numbers $16,17,23,24,39,40$.

If there is solution of $4$ darts, then set $\color{green}{B}$ would have common element with the set $\color{red}{A}$.

There are no $3$-darts solutions, no $4$-darts solutions.

**B)** Consider $5$- and $6$-darts combinations.

If solution has large number like $39$ or $40$, then the sum of all other ($4$ or $5$) numbers will be $61$ or $60$.  Impossible, since even $16+16+16+16$ is greater than $61$.

So, solution consists of small numbers like $16,17,23,24$.

If it has number $23$ or $24$, then the sum of all other numbers is $77$ or $76$. Since $16+16+16+16+16>77$, then this sum of other numbers consists of $4$ numbers.

(Show that it is impossible to compose number $76$ or $77$ of four numbers of the set $\{16,17,23,24\}$).

So, solution consists of numbers $16$ and $17$ solely.

Now:

- How many darts are required for the solution?
- Find this solution.
- Why solution cannot have $7$ or more darts?

Comment: The solution cannot have 7 or more darts, because 7 times the lowest number $7 \cdot 16$ already exceeds 100. The number of darts required are 6: $(4 \cdot 17) + (2 \cdot 16)$. Interesting to see that for such a simple puzzle still requires quite some work to figure out!